# Linq orderby same field different value

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this query:

```
investorData = from investor in db.Investors
               join loanapp in db.LoanApplications on investor.FundID equals loanapp.FundID into loanAppData
               from lapp in loanAppData.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join fundreport in db.FundReportLoanDatas on lapp.LoanId equals fundreport.LoanId into fundReportData
               from freport in fundReportData.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where investor.FundID == fundID
               orderby lapp.LoanId descending
               select new InvestorPortfolioVM()
               {
                   InvestorId = investor.InvestorID,
                   CurrentLTV = freport.CurrentLTV == null ? 0.0 : freport.CurrentLTV,
                   LoanId = lapp.LoanId,
                   SegLTV = freport.SegLTV == string.Empty ? "" : freport.SegLTV,
                   BorrowerName = lapp.BorrowerName,
                   LoanStatusId = lapp.LoanStatusId
               };
```

What I want to achieve now is to order the items by one field, LoanStatusId beginning with loans which don't have LoanStatusId of 4 or 8.

Any idea how I can achieve that?

Comment: Do you want 4-8 to be on the bottom unordered or you don't want the at all?

Comment: @FilipCordas at the bottom thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
investorData = from investor in db.Investors
               join loanapp in db.LoanApplications on investor.FundID equals loanapp.FundID into loanAppData
               from lapp in loanAppData.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join fundreport in db.FundReportLoanDatas on lapp.LoanId equals fundreport.LoanId into fundReportData
               from freport in fundReportData.DefaultIfEmpty()
               where investor.FundID == fundID
               orderby (lapp.LoanId >= 4 &&  lapp.LoanId <= 8) ? 1 : 0
               select new InvestorPortfolioVM()
               {
                   InvestorId = investor.InvestorID,
                   CurrentLTV = freport.CurrentLTV == null ? 0.0 : freport.CurrentLTV,
                   LoanId = lapp.LoanId,
                   SegLTV = freport.SegLTV == string.Empty ? "" : freport.SegLTV,
                   BorrowerName = lapp.BorrowerName,
                   LoanStatusId = lapp.LoanStatusId
               };
```